# How to update an adaptive card which is already sent to user from BOT?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have already sent the card with capturing the details and with buttons.After clicking on submit from task module which will save details through http API here the activity type is Invoke. 
Now i have to update the existing adaptive Card.

I have the code to update the message, but how to update the card or resend the card again.

```
                connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {activity.Text.Length} characters");
                var msgToUpdate = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                Activity updatedReply = activity.CreateReply($"This is an updated message");
                await connector.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(reply.Conversation.Id, msgToUpdate.Id, updatedReply);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This involves few steps.

1. Create an Adaptive card and add unique id (GUID) in adaptive card action.

   ```
   var Card = new AdaptiveCard()
   {
         Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
   {
       new AdaptiveTextBlock(){Text="This is a test adaptive card"}
   },
   Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
   {
       new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
       {
           Title="UpdateMe",
           DataJson= @"{'id':'uniqueId'}"
       }
   }
   };
   ```
2. After sending message keep mapping of adaptive card uniqueId and message id.

   ```
   connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
   reply = activity.CreateReply();
   reply.Attachments.Add(Card.ToAttachment());
   var msgToUpdate = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
   // Keep mapping of uniqueId and messageToUpdate.Id
   // UniqueId1 => messageId1
   // UniqueId2 => messageId2
   ```
3. When user clicks on UpdateMe action button, check the mapping for `uniqueId` (This will be in `activity.Value`).
4. Create new card and call `connector.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync` with updated code.

Let us knwo if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can update adaptive card in channel like MS Teams not in directline. For updating card you need Accessor to store ActivityId which is generated while sending current message.

Here I have provided the way to update message

[Code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62710643/7885585)