# Dynamically create adaptive card bot framework azure

Tags: python, json, azure, botframework

i have a problem using adaptive card JSON into python web chat bot (BotFrameWork), i want to know how to customize values in the JSON element, these values are dynamic. I explain more i have to do a list of books information in one card, but title,author,etc... changes everytime. So how i can fill values dynamically?
That's my json file

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "RISULTATI",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                        "spacing": "None",
                        "size": "Large",
                        "color": "Attention",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "separator": true,
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Nome Libro e autore",
                        "isSubtle": true,
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Prezzo",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Disponibilità",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Link",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Genere",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                        "isSubtle": true,
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "wrap": true
                    }   
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "separator": true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Prezzo",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Disponibilità",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Link",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                   
                ]
            }
          
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have to fill the text values in items, how i should do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Adaptive Cards SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards) doesn't have Python support, unfortunately, so you won't be able to make dynamic cards directly in your bot code. However, you can still use [Adaptive Card Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/), so your cards can be somewhat dynamic, although it's limited to the data you include in the card.

So, you really have two options:

1. Change from Python to .NET or JS, or
2. Write your card JSON, load it in Python, and edit it dynamically in your code before attaching it to an activity. I go over that a bit in #3, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173267/ms-chat-bot-how-to-access-custom-adaptive-card-properties-from-my-c-sharp-code/56192868#56192868)--it's in C#, but the same concept applies.